# Email Validation in Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to validate the email input box to return an error when it is empty or when it does not match the email regex pattern. If email input is empty I should get an error and if email input is not empty but does not meet the pattern I should get a new error. So far I am only getting one error

```js
const form = document.querySelector("form"),
  user = document.getElementById("name"),
  email = document.getElementById("email"),
  emailField = document.getElementById("email-field"),
  msg = document.getElementById("comment"),
  errorMsg = document.getElementsByClassName("error"),
  container1 = document.getElementById("form-container"),
  container2 = document.getElementById("form-container2");


let field = (id, serial, message) => {
  if (id.value.trim() === "") {
    errorMsg[serial].innerHTML = message;
    id.classList.add("invalid");
  } else {
    errorMsg[serial].innerHTML = "";
    id.classList.remove("invalid");
  }
}

// Email Validtion
function checkEmail() {
  const emaiPattern = /^[^ ]+@[^ ]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$/;
  if (!email.value.match(emaiPattern)) {
    console.log("no match");
    errorMsg[1].innerHTML = "message";
    // email.classList.add("invalid"); //adding invalid class if email value do not mathced with email pattern
  } else {
    console.log("matches");
    // emailField.classList.remove("invalid"); //removing invalid class if email value matched with emaiPattern
  }
}

form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  field(user, 0, "Name cannot be blank");
  field(email, 1, "Email cannot be blank");
  field(msg, 2, "Message cannot be blank");

  checkEmail();

  if (!user.classList.contains("invalid") &&
    !email.classList.contains("invalid") &&
    !msg.classList.contains("invalid")
  ) {
    location.href = form.getAttribute("action");
    container1.classList.add("hide");
    container2.classList.remove("hide");
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="form-field">
  <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Email Address">
  <div class="error"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is your problem exactly? You commented out the line that adds the class which you use in the validation logic to see if it is valid. Note: you are reinventing HTML5 validation. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation

Comment: Surprisingly, proper mail validation can be really difficult. Try looking at [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/how-can-i-validate-an-email-address-using-a-regular-expression) for more details. But it really depends on your needs, maybe just checking for `something@(something.)*something` would be enough for you

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. Also take the [tour].

Comment: When i click submit message whilst the email box is empty, i get an error for checkEmail not for email cannot be blank. I only want to see the CheckEmail error when i type something in without matching the pattern

Comment: why not `if (email.value == '') { /* FIELD IS EMPTY */ } else if...`

Comment: You should include a form element in the demo above so the script doesn't throw an error.